# VueJS computed property using boolean prop not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue (2.6.11 via Nuxt) component that gets a Boolean property from its parent and uses it to calculate additional computed properties. After the initial rendering all values are shown as expected. However, when a parent flips the value of the passed-down property, only some values change in this component. Specifically DIVs bound directly to the property and `original` are both fine, but `flipped` and `stringed` never change again.

Assigning the original property to a local `var` before any evaluation within the computed property function makes no difference in the outcome.

Changing computed properties to methods doesn't solve the issue either. It is still just the first two that update properly.

Note that the code below is stripped to a bare minimum to demonstrate the issue.

```
<template>
  <div class="x">
    <div class="y">
      <div class="x">
        <div>{{ flag }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="x">  
        <div>{{ original }}</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="x">  
        <div>{{ flipped }}</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="x">  
        <div>{{ stringed }}</div>
      </div>  
    </div> 
  </div>    
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "FlagBox",
  props: { 
    "flag": {
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  computed: {
    original: function() {
      return this.flag;
    },
    flipped: function() {
      return !this.flag;
    },
    stringed: function() {
      return this.flag ? "yes" : "no";
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: is the name of your original prop also flag?

Comment: How are you evaluating the value in the parent? can you show an example?

Comment: @RaduDiță What do you mean by "original prop"? The parent uses `v-bind:flag` directive.

Comment: @FaranAli There is a radio button group in another component emmiting event to the root app which in turn updates the flag (which is originally declared in `data` block there). I wanna point out that the changes are in fact getting into the component above, two of the four DIVs are updating properly.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce. Maybe try to create a https://codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the issue but my best guess is that the radio button you are using is emitting a string value (e.g., "false" instead of false) which is causing it to be true even when it's not.
Please check your props using the vue devtools to verify the data type being passed.
There is no other possible explanation for this, the code seems fine.

Comment: Ouch... That was it, I did not notice in the devtools the value is `"true"` (String) and not `true`. Thank you.